# iOS: How can i get "GPS lon" and "GPS lat" from this array?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Search results is an array,

```
Search results: (
   "Type: 9 ; Id: 0 ; Name: CMH Family Wing  ; GPS lon: 71.538612 ; GPS lat: 34.002556 ; Category: 124 ; MainCategory: 2 ; textureID: 33 ; Nr. of;",
   "Type: 9 ; Id: 0 ; Name: CMH Peshawar - Central Military Hospital  ; GPS lon: 71.542702 ; GPS lat: 34.003410 ; Category: 124 ; MainCategory: 2 ; textureID: 33 ; Nr. of;"
)
```

Comment: Why is the data an array of strings with `;` seperator and not a dictionary?

Comment: i am also confused. Actually i am using Skobbler Map, in which i am searching for nearby places, this function is called when i search for some place
-(void)searchService:(SKSearchService *)searchService didRetrieveNearbySearchResults:(NSArray *)searchResults withSearchMode:(SKSearchMode)searchMode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function below

```
-(void)searchService:(SKSearchService *)searchService didRetrieveNearbySearchResults:(NSArray *)searchResults withSearchMode:(SKSearchMode)searchMode;
```

Returns array of `SKSearchResult` objects, the `SKSearchResult` class contains all properties you need to process, see below

```
-(void)searchService:(SKSearchService *)searchService didRetrieveNearbySearchResults:(NSArray *)searchResults withSearchMode:(SKSearchMode)searchMode{

    for(SKSearchResult *result in searchResults){
       NSLog(@"Lat = %f, Lon = %f",result.coordinate.latitude,result.coordinate.longitude);
    }

}
```

Look [here](https://developer.skobbler.com/docs/ios/2.5.0/Classes/SKSearchResult.html) for more information.

Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

Search results is an array of dictionaries, you can iterate through results array, and use method `[NSDictionary objectForKey:@""]` to get each “GPS lon” and “GPS lat” from this array.

```
NSString *lonStr = [dic objectForKey:@"GPS lon"];
NSString *latStr = [dic objectForKey:@"GPS lat"];
```